# How to make dependent picklists work in lightning component in aura iteration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist

I am working on last few days on how to get the dependent picklist work when it is more than one record inside aura iteration. I apologize if this seems like I am asking for solution, but I am not and I did my homework and this is where I am stuck.

Here is the sample code:

**ExampleApp.app**:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<aura:attribute name="dataArray" type="List"/>

<aura:attribute name="stateList" type="List"/>

<aura:attribute name="stateCityMap" type="Object"/>

<div aura:id="parent-aura-div-id">
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:10px;">Row #</th>
                <th style="width:20px;">State</th>
                <th style="width:20px;">City</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.dataArray}" var="dataVar">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!dataVar.name}</td>
                    <td id="{! dataVar.name + '_state_td'}">
                        <select class="slds-select" 
                                id="{! dataVar.name + '_state'}" 
                                onchange="{!c.stateChanged}">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.stateList}" var="stateVar">
                                <option text="{!stateVar}" 
                                        selected="{! stateVar eq dataVar.state}"/>  
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td id="{! dataVar.name +'_city_td'}">
                        <select class="slds-select" 
                                id="{! dataVar.name + '_city'}">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>               
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**ExampleAppController.js:**

```
({

    doInit: function(component,event,helper){
        var dataArray = [];
        dataArray.push({name:'1',state:'MA',city:'Boston'},{name:'2',state:'NY',city:'NYC'});
        component.set('v.dataArray',dataArray);

        var stateList = [];
        stateList.push('MA','NY');
        component.set('v.stateList',stateList); 

        var stateCityMap = {};
        stateCityMap['MA'] = [];
        stateCityMap['MA'].push('Boston','Boston_X');
        stateCityMap['NY'] = [];
        stateCityMap['NY'].push('NYC','NYC_X');
        component.set('v.stateCityMap',stateCityMap);               
    },

    stateChanged: function(component,event,helper){
        var rowId = event.target.id.split('_')[0];
        var stateSelected = event.target.value;
        var citySelElem = component.find('parent-aura-div-id').getElement().querySelector('[id="'+rowId + '_city"]');
        var stateCityMap = component.get('v.stateCityMap');
        var cityArray = stateCityMap[stateSelected];
        var innerHTMLVar = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < cityArray.length; i++) {
            innerHTMLVar = innerHTMLVar + '<option value="' + cityArray[i]+ '">' +cityArray[i] +'</option>';  
        }
        citySelElem.innerHTML = innerHTMLVar;
    }
})
```

Output(I was able to get so far):

[image]

1. As we can see in the gif above, I am stuck on how to populate the dependent field on the initial load.
2. Once the controlling field is changed, I am able to change the options in the dependent picklist successfully.
3. I feel this would have been solved easily, if we can iterate map collection with dynamic key but it is not possible.

Comment: why cannot you call Statechanged on do init?

Comment: Hmm. I didn't think of that but let me try.

Comment: @ManjotSingh, I just tried and it is not working because when the init method is running, the DOM is not ready so I am not able to set options for city picklist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was looking into the documentation, I found this [`aura:render`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_render_handler.htm) event and then with the below modifications, I was able to get it working.

Added the below line in the component:

`<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>`

Added this new method in the controller:

```
onRender : function(component,event,helper){
        debugger;
        console.log('From Render method');
        var rootElem = component.find('parent-aura-div-id').getElement();
        var stateElemArray = rootElem.querySelectorAll('select[id$="_state"]');
        var stateCityMap = component.get('v.stateCityMap');
        var dataArray = component.get('v.dataArray');
        for (var i = 0; i < stateElemArray.length; i++) {
            console.log(stateElemArray[i].value);
            var rowId = stateElemArray[i].id.split('_')[0];
            var citySelElem = rootElem.querySelector('select[id$="' + rowId +'_city"]');
            var cityArray = stateCityMap[stateElemArray[i].value];
            var innerHTMLVar = '';
            for (var j = 0; j < cityArray.length; j++) {
                if(cityArray[j] == dataArray[rowId-1].city){
                    innerHTMLVar = innerHTMLVar + '<option value="' + cityArray[j]+ '" selected="true">'+ cityArray[j] +'</option>';    
                }else{
                    innerHTMLVar = innerHTMLVar + '<option value="' + cityArray[j]+ '">'+ cityArray[j] +'</option>';
                }
            }
            citySelElem.innerHTML = innerHTMLVar;           
        }
    }
```

I will keep this question open in case anyone finds a risk with handling `render` event.

**UPDATE**: Gist URL with the complete code : https://gist.github.com/sfdcale/c9bbd38771c2ff9946e4d7035b9ef2e1

Comment: I do think this is best Approach