# Dependent picklists using ui:inputselect inside aura:iteration in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I've tried in vain to make dependent picklists work inside an iteration.  Please see code below:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.displayDTORecord}" var="item">
<tr class="slds-hint-parent">
    <aura:iteration items="{!item.lstFieldVal}" var="f">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!f.field_api == 'Name'}">
            <td role="gridcell" data-label="{!f.field_api}">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!f.value}">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="{!item.recId}" onclick="{!c.doRedirect}"><span>{!f.value}</span></a>
                </div>
            </td> 
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <td role="gridcell" data-label="{!f.field_api}">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!f.field_api != 'Additional_Details__c'}">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!f.inputField == false}">
                        <div class="no-text-overflow slds-truncate" title="{!f.value}">{!f.value}</div>
                    <aura:set attribute="else">

                        <aura:if isTrue="{!f.field_api == 'Offer_Status__c'}">
            <!--            
                            <div class="slds-form-element">
                                <div class="slds-select_container">
                                    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="{!f.field_api_idx}" change="{!c.onControllerTOFieldChange}" value="{!f.value}"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            -->
                            <lightning:select name="mySelect" label="" aura:id="{!f.field_api_idx}" value="{!f.value}">
                                 <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
                                    <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </lightning:select>
                            <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <div class="slds-form-element">
                                    <div class="slds-select_container">
                                        <ui:inputSelect aura:id="Offer_Outcome__c" disabled="{!v.isDependentDisableTO}" change="{!c.onDependentTOFieldChange}" value="{!f.value}" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </aura:set>
                        </aura:if>                                                                          
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
```

EDIT: **CONTROLLER**

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper){

    helper.fetchTOPicklistValues(component, 'Offer_Status__c', 'Offer_Outcome__c');

},  

// function call onchange controller field  
onControllerTOFieldChange: function(component, event, helper) {

    // get the selected value
    var controllerValueKey = event.getSource().get("v.value");

    // get the map values   
    var Map = component.get("v.dependentFieldMap");

    // check if selected value is not equal to None then call the helper function.
    // if controller field value is none then make dependent field value is none and disable field
    if (controllerValueKey != '-- None --') {

        // get dependent values for controller field by using map[key].  
        var ListOfDependentFields = Map[controllerValueKey];
        helper.fetchDepValuesType(component, ListOfDependentFields);

    } else {
        var defaultVal = [{
        class: "optionClass",
        label: '-- None --',
        value: '-- None --'
        }];
        component.find('Offer_Outcome__c').set("v.options", defaultVal);
        component.set("v.isDependentDisableTO", false);

    }
},

onDependentTOFieldChange: function(component, event, helper) {

    var onDep = event.getSource().get("v.value");

},
```

**HELPER:**

```
        fetchTOPicklistValues: function(component, controllerField, dependentField) {

      // call the server side function  
      var action = component.get("c.getFieldDependencies");
      // pass parameters [object name, controller field name, dependent field name]
      // to server side function 

      action.setParams({
         'objApiName': component.get("v.objTOInfo"),
         'contrfieldApiName': controllerField,
         'depfieldApiName': dependentField
      });

      //set callback   
      action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

         if (response.getState() == "SUCCESS") {

            //store the return response from server (map<string,List<string>>)  
            var StoreResponse = response.getReturnValue();

            // once set #StoreResponse to dependentFieldMap attribute 
            component.set("v.dependentFieldMap", StoreResponse);

            // create a empty array for store map keys(@@--->which is controller picklist values) 
            var listOfkeys = []; // for store all map keys (controller picklist values)
            var ControllerField = []; // for store controller picklist value to set on ui field. 

            // play a for loop on Return map 
            // and fill the all map key on listOfkeys variable.
            for (var singlekey in StoreResponse) {

               listOfkeys.push(singlekey);

            }

            //set the controller field value for ui:inputSelect  
            if (listOfkeys != undefined && listOfkeys.length > 0) {

               ControllerField.push({
                  class: "optionClass",
                  label: "-- None --",
                  value: "-- None --"
               });

            }

            for (var i = 0; i < listOfkeys.length; i++) {

               ControllerField.push({
                  class: "optionClass",
                  label: listOfkeys[i],
                  value: listOfkeys[i]
               });

            }

            // set the ControllerField variable values to controller picklist field
            component.find("Offer_Status__c0").set("v.options", ControllerField);
         } else {

            console.log("ERROR : ", response);
            var errors = action.getError();
            console.log('ERROR Val : ', response.getError());

         }
      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
   },
```

My problems are:
1) looking at the ui:inputSelect(s), I am unable to reference an index in aura:id that I am able to component.find back in the controller to pass back the picklist values.
2) I believe same thing will happen to the lightning:select because I will still need to reference an aura:id.

In my mind, I need a way to issue unique aura:ids for each of the records. I thought that by creating an index it will resolve the issue but I couldn't reference it back in the controller. Is there still a way through this and if so, what options do I have or workaround to be able to make this work? Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: you can't dynamically assign aura:id's

Comment: Yes I'm resigned to that fact now. But will there be a workaround, say if I don't use tags with aura:id, like in this example. [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184613/how-to-make-dependent-picklists-work-in-lightning-component-in-aura-iteration). Just not sure how to convert my code to that one.

Comment: i didnt really look at all the logic in your code, but is there any reason why you are not using some other component such as lightning:recordEditform which handles FLS, crud, field dependencies for you? and based on the object API name, render different fieldname input fields ?

Comment: I did try [that](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223638/rerender-lightninginputfield-to-activate-dependent-picklists-that-are-generated), and unfortunately, that does not work in this use case. It seems that both the controlling and dependent picklists need to be rendered at the same time with the tag. In this case, because of the iteration, the controlling picklist is rendered first and at the point, Lightning issues an error as it could not find the dependent picklist.

Comment: instead of using aura:iteration, have you tryied dynamically creating your components? "$A.createComponent()" ?

Comment: No, but that's quite new to me. I've seen that in some places with examples but I couldn't imagine how it will work. Do you have something I can start with? Thanks.

Comment: Just mentioning here that I've gone through to dynamic component solution, only that  I couldn't figure out how to [properly generate the component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224750/syntax-error-of-dynamically-created-lightningselect-and-auraiteration).